# How to append the new data to a column in mysql

Tags: mysql

Hello guys can we append the data to a particular column of mysql table.

Lets say I have a column "History".It initially has the value as "Stack". Is there a way to append the data such as "overflow" to History column. So finally History column becomes "Satckoverflow".

I know one way that is first query the value of "History" column and store it in a string and add the required value to string and finally update the column with the new value. It works but it needs two database requests so is there any better way of doing this. If there then please let me know guys.

Comment: your question is vague and without any code and db structure is hard to help you. Post some relevant code and we can help you. Anyway you are doing two different kinds of queries. So even using a subquery to get the previous result the efficency won't be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Table SET History=CONCAT(History,'overflow');
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul it worked. You understood my question well.

Comment: Hey if my History is null at first then whole column becomes null as well what am i do for that??

Comment: At first it is null then lets say i executed below query     UPDATE project SET history = concat(history,"Sumanth uploaded a file") where filename = "hello.txt";    After executing this I got history column with respect to filename "hello.txt" as null. It's not updated.

Comment: @SumanthUdupa:- I am asking when it is null, what value you want? Stackoverflow or simply overflow or do you want it to be null only?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88314/discussion-between-sumanth-udupa-and-rahul-tripathi).